# Official term for the tendency to associate with like-minded people?

Tags: social-psychology, terminology

I want a term for the tendency of individuals to confirm their existing biases/opinions by seeking out and reinforcing their opinions with like-minded individuals (as far as I know, this is distinct from confirmation bias).

Comment: I've seen this phenomenon referred to as "homophilic bubble" when it happens at work, and your coworkers views reinforce your own. Apparently same can happen with internet searches: http://csci12vp.blogspot.com/2014/03/internet-homophilic-bubble.html

Comment: @AlexStone it beats the alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self-selection bias is probably the best domain specific term. Generally, this is called assortativity, as in assortative mating.